# Rust Inspect Iterator: cannot borrow `*` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: iterator, rust, lazy-evaluation, borrowing

Why can't I `push` to this vector during `inspect` and do `contains` on it during `skip_while`?

I've implemented my own iterator for my own struct `Chain` like this:

```
struct Chain {
    n: u32,
}

impl Chain {
    fn new(start: u32) -> Chain {
        Chain { n: start }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Chain {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.n = digit_factorial_sum(self.n);
        Some(self.n)
    }
}
```

Now what I'd like to do it `take` while the iterator is producing unique values. So I'm `inspect`-ing the chain and pushing to a vector and then checking it in a `take_while` scope:

```
let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(terms);
Chain::new(i)
    .inspect(|&x| {
        v.push(x)
    })
    .skip_while(|&x| {
        return v.contains(&x);
    })
```

However, the Rust compile spits out this error:

```
error: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable [E0502]
...
borrow occurs due to use of `v` in closure
    return v.contains(&x);
           ^
previous borrow of `v` occurs here due to use in closure; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `v` until the borrow ends
    .inspect(|&x| {
        v.push(x)
    })
```

Obviously I don't understand the concept of "borrowing". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Likely the issue has to do with your attempt at closing over a variable that is somewhere in another scope (`v`). This is very important in Rust.. so we'll need to see where `v` comes from, how its declared and how you're referencing it within the current scope.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead edited to include `v`. Must've left it out earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're attempting to create both a mutable and an immutable reference to the same variable, which is a violation of Rust borrowing rules. And rustc actually does say this to you very clearly.

```
let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(terms);
Chain::new(i)
    .inspect(|&x| {
        v.push(x)
    })
    .skip_while(|&x| {
        return v.contains(&x);
    })
```

Here you're trying to use `v` in two closures, first in `inspect()` argument, second in `skip_while()` argument. Non-`move` closures capture their environment by reference, so the environment of the first closure contains `&mut v`, and that of the second closure contains `&v`. Closures are created in the same expression, so even if it was guaranteed that `inspect()` ran and dropped the borrow before `skip_while()` (which I is not the actual case, because these are iterator adapters and they won't be run at all until the iterator is consumed), due to lexical borrowing rules this is prohibited.

Unfortunately, this is one of those examples when the borrow checker is overly strict. What you can do is to use [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which allows mutation through a shared reference but introduces some run-time cost:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

let mut v = RefCell::new(Vec::with_capacity(terms));
Chain::new(i)
    .inspect(|x| v.borrow_mut().push(*x))
    .skip_while(|x| v.borrow().contains(x))
```

I *think* it may be possible to avoid runtime penalty of `RefCell` and use [`UnsafeCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) instead, because when the iterator is consumed, these closures will only run one after another, not at the same time, so there should never be a mutable and an immutable references outstanding at the same time. It could look like this:

```
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

let mut v = UnsafeCell::new(Vec::with_capacity(terms));
Chain::new(i)
    .inspect(|x| unsafe { (&mut *v.get()).push(*x) })
    .skip_while(|x| unsafe { (&*v.get()).contains(x) })
```

But I may be wrong, and anyway, the overhead of `RefCell` is not that high unless this code is running in a *really* tight loop, so you should only use `UnsafeCell` as a last resort, only when nothing else works, and exercise extreme caution when working with it.

Comment: This is a good explanation, however, both your solutions break the iterator for some reason. I can't figure it out. It's almost as if the `skip_while` isn't stopping the iteration in the way it usually does and it searches forever. Either that or it's over 100x slower (I waited ~1min and it never finished).

Comment: I was able to implement a solution by moving all the `push`/`contains` logic into the iterator `next()` function: https://github.com/JacksonGariety/euler.rs/blob/master/src/solution_074.rs

Comment: That's pretty efficient, however, I'd like to move the logic into a `skip_while` if possible. When I use both your implementations, the `skip_while` either skips all iterations or the iterator just runs forever.

Comment: @JacksonGariety, I've just written an example program using this approach and understood that it can't work. When you ask an iterator chain for a next element, it works through the entire chain. So suppose you're calling `next()` on the above chain with `inspect()` and `skip_while()` (I think that it should actually be `take_while()` with an inverted condition, otherwise it doesn't make sense). An element is taken from the original iterator and written to the collection. And then the collection is queried for this element. Naturally, it is already there, so the iteration stops immediately.

Comment: @JacksonGariety therefore, your approach for internalizing the collection into the iterator is *the* way to go. Although I would use `HashSet` instead of `Vec` because `contains()` is much more efficient on `HashSet` than on `Vec`.

Comment: Your explanation *really* changed the way I look at iterators in Rust. Thanks! In this case, however, the HashSet performs about 2x slower than Vec. Not sure why.

Comment: Ah, I think that HashSet is slower because it uses SipHash which is rather slow for small keys but cryptographically strong hash function. For integer keys it makes sense to use something else, like [`fnv`](https://crates.io/crates/fnv).

Comment: okay I tried using a `HashSet<u32, BuildHasherDefault<FnvHasher>>` instead of a vector and it ran ~1.17x slow. How can that be? Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/JacksonGariety/a6bb4672a549e381c06415398a78ffc3

Comment: Tried XxHash also and it was wayyyyy slower.

Comment: @JacksonGariety, sorry, I'm afraid I won't be able to help more on this one, I'm not very strong in performance analysis :) I suspect that a vector may be more efficient on small numbers of elements than a hash set regardless of a hash function, but I cannot say for sure. You can try asking on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/) or on [discussions forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) if you're interested in this.